# Get the port of the local HTTP server without hijacking the connection

Tags: go

In a http handler is there a way to get the port of the server that received the request without using `http.Hijacker` to get the TCP connection, if there isn't is there a way to hijack the connection but still use the provided `http.ResponseWriter`

Comment: It will be whatever port the server was started on. A server instance only listens on one port.

Comment: Yes, but what if I'm using the same handler for multiple HTTP servers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the local address from the [request context](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Context) using [http.LocalAddrContextKey](https://godoc.org/net/http#LocalAddrContextKey).

```
a, ok := req.Context().Value(http.LocalAddrContextKey).(net.Addr)
if !ok {
    // handle address not found
}
```

Get the TCP port from the address:

```
ta, ok := a.(*net.TCPAddr)
if !ok {
    // handle unknown address type
}
port := ta.Port
```